# predict in caret ConfusionMatrix is removing rows

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm fairly new to using the caret library and it's causing me some problems. Any
help/advice would be appreciated. My situations are as follows:

I'm trying to run a general linear model on some data and, when I run it
through the `confusionMatrix`, I get 'the data and reference factors must have
the same number of levels'. I know what this error means (I've run into it before), but I've double and triple checked my data manipulation and it all looks correct (I'm using the right variables in the right places), so I'm not sure why the two values in the `confusionMatrix` are disagreeing. I've run almost the exact same code for a different variable and it works fine.

I went through every variable and everything was balanced until I got to the
`confusionMatrix` predict. I discovered this by doing the following:

```
 a <- table(testing2$hold1yes0no)

 a[1]+a[2]


1543

 b <- table(predict(modelFit,trainTR2))

 dim(b)

[1] 1538
```

Those two values shouldn't disagree. Where are the missing 5 rows?

My code is below:

```
set.seed(2382)

inTrain2 <- createDataPartition(y=HOLD$hold1yes0no, p = 0.6, list = FALSE)

training2 <- HOLD[inTrain2,]

testing2 <- HOLD[-inTrain2,]

preProc2 <- preProcess(training2[-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)], method="BoxCox")

trainPC2 <- predict(preProc2, training2[-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)])

trainTR2 <- predict(preProc2, testing2[-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)])

modelFit <- train(training2$hold1yes0no ~ ., method ="glm", data = trainPC2)

confusionMatrix(testing2$hold1yes0no, predict(modelFit,trainTR2))
```

Comment: you did predict on trainTR2, and you checked the length of testing2$hold1yes0no.. these are two different dataframes, you would get different lengths... i don't quite understand your issue here

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as I don't know your data structure, but I wonder if this is due to the way you set up your `modelFit`, using the formula method.  In this case, you are specifying `y = training2$hold1yes0no` and x = everything else.  Perhaps you should try:

```
modelFit <- train(trainPC2, training2$hold1yes0no, method="glm")
```

Which specifies `y = training2$hold1yes0no` and `x = trainPC2`.